# Derivative of $ y = \frac{1}{\ln^{2}x} $

Tags: derivatives

I am supposed to find the derivative of $ y = \frac{1}{\ln^{2}x} $.  How would you calculate it? My first step was to do this: $\frac{-1\ast \ln^{2}x}{(\ln^{2}x)^{2}}$. How would you continue? I don't know what to do with $ \ln^{2}x $. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are differentiating
$$ \frac{1}{(\ln x)^2} = f(g(x)), $$
where
$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}, \quad g(x) = \ln x. $$
Since
$$ f'(x) = -\frac{2}{x^3}, \quad g'(x) = \frac{1}{x}, $$
the chain rule therefore gives
$$ \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \frac{1}{(\ln x)^2} = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} f(g(x)) = f'(g(x))g'(x) = -\frac{2}{(\ln x)^3} \frac{1}{x}. $$
You could do it even more directly:
$$ \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \frac{1}{(\ln x)^2} = -\frac{2}{(\ln x)^3}\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\ln x = -\frac{2}{x(\ln x)^3}. $$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Use the chain rule, and remember that
$$\biggl(\frac1{x^2}\biggr)'=-\frac 2{x^3},\enspace\text{more generally: }\quad\biggl(\frac1{x^n}\biggr)'=-\frac n{x^{n+1}}$$

Answer (score 0):

A rule that always hold is $(u^n)' = nu'u^{n-1}$.

With $u = ln$ we get $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^*_+, u^{-2}(x) = \frac{-2}{x}ln^{-3}(x)$.